# Resonant Q Factor vs Voltage Gain

Tags: passive-networks, resonance, tesla-coil

I was pondering the analytic effect of Q on the voltage gain for quarter wavelength helical resonators (Tesla Coil Secondary). One of the reasons a great looking secondary can perform poorly is due to a low Q, typically caused by winding on a material that is lossy at RF frequencies. From an analytical point, does an identical set up containing a resonator with a Q, vs 2Q have a specific expected voltage gain difference?

**Question:**
If I have a resonant system, How does Q affect peak resonant voltage, i.e. does a doubling of Q result in double the power being stored in the system? Or my interest is specifically voltage, so
**Is this correct?** \$ 2Q \space\approx \space \sqrt{2}*V_{pk} \space\$

**My Logic:**

I have seen Q generically described below:

\$Q\colon= 2{\pi}f_r \times \frac{E_{stored}}{P_{Loss}}\$

Given the above info, assuming \$P_{Loss}\$ is constant in a given system due to consistent \$R_{DC}\$.
Then \$E_{stored}\$ Must double, given a steady state system, this effectively doubles the Power consumed, so \$ 2 \times Power => \sqrt{2} \space V\$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If I have a resonant system, How does Q affect peak resonant voltage,
> i.e. does a doubling of Q result in double the power being stored in
> the system?*

If you are considering applying a sine wave to a highly resonant tuned circuit then, at resonance, the output voltage is the input voltage multiplied by \$Q\$. Consider this RLC circuit: -

[image]

As for the math, it's fairly straightforward to show that a low pass RLC filter (for example) has a transfer function equation thus: -

$$H(j\omega) = \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{\omega^2}{\omega_n^2}+j\frac{2\zeta\omega}{\omega_n}}$$

And, at resonance \$\omega = \omega_n\$ hence: -

$$H(j\omega) = \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1}+j\frac{2\zeta}{1}} = \dfrac{-j}{2\zeta} = -jQ$$

So, at resonance the transfer function has a magnitude of \$Q\$ phase shifted by 90°. See the orange circles below: -

[image]

And, given that we are only interested in highly resonant circuits (where Q is quite or very large), we can say without fear of significant error, that an accurate measure of the peak of resonance has an amplitude (\$V_{OUT}\$) that is \$Q \times V_{IN}\$.

However, if you take power from \$V_{OUT}\$ then you are taking current and thus the "loading" acts like a resistor. This means that Q is then subject to the following formula: -

$$Q = R_{load}\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac{C}{L}}$$

And, in all these systems, power-out equals power-in minus losses. There is no power gain; only voltage gain.

So, in summary, \$Q\$ defines the output voltage amplification at resonance and \$Q\$ is determined by the capacitance, inductance and load resistance.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I though, then I over thought about it and decided it was not 1 to 1...